# ajax redirect does not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a Login form where there are two fields - `username` and `password`.
I am using ajax to send this variables to `login.php` which works.
Now I need to get the `data` back from `login.php` so I do this:

```
$.post('login.php',{username:username,password:password},
 function(data)
 {
    $('#data').html(data);
    if (data=='login'){
        window.location="http://www.google.co.uk";

    }

 });
```

The problem is the code should redirect to `http://www.google.co.uk` 
if only the data is `== login`But it doesnt. please help thanks!

Comment: try `window.location.href`

Comment: what are you getting in response

Comment: why not use header(); function 
ex. header('Location: link');

Comment: that was my first approch but it doesnt redirect throught ajax call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed the `href`

```
window.location.href="http://www.google.co.uk";
```

Comment: I don't think so, it should work without href. Hmm in html4. About 5-10 years ago... :D

Answer (score 0):

You can write this if you want to redirect to a new page.
window.open(http://www.google.co.uk,"_parent","toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=1000, height=850");

If you want to open another window without clearing the contents of the present window,use
window.open(http://www.google.co.uk,"_blank","toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=1000, height=850");